# Jira Python Library Import "jira" could not be resolved

Tags: jira

I've tried all manner of trying to get the Jira library to import in python but keep getting the Import "jira" pylacne report missing imports error. My terminal is full of requirement already satisfied statements after running python3 -m pip install jira.

Any ideas for how I can get this to go? I have tried running python 3.9.6/7 and 3.11 without success.

Thank you,

-Nate

I attempted installing the library using -m pip install jira was attempted and expected to have a working library.

Comment: Have you tried with `from jira import JIRA` as shown in the [description](https://pypi.org/project/jira/)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by running python 3.9.